# Simple method to check if user is already in SQLite database is not working

Tags: android, sqlite

I have been trying to make it so users who have already registered with one email cannot register again with the same email in android studios. However I have tried many different codes and none of them seem to work for different reasons, I was looking around and found

```
public boolean checkAlreadyExist(String email)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String query = null;{
            query = (SELECT + COL_5 + FROM + TABLE_NAME + WHERE + COL_5 + " =?");
        }
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{email});
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
```

I don't understand why it wouldn't work when I tried it. 'SELECT' had the error message:

> Field requires API level 24 (current min is 15):
>   android.icu.text.MessagePattern.ArgType#SELECT

, and `FROM`, `WHERE`, had the error code:

> could not resolve symbol

, and `"=?"` had the error code:

> `<statement>` expected

I have tried to Invalidate Caches and download many tools from the SDK manager however nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change this line:

```
query = (SELECT + COL_5 + FROM + TABLE_NAME + WHERE + COL_5 + " =?");
```

into this:

```
query = "SELECT "+ COL_5 +" FROM "+ TABLE_NAME +" WHERE "+ COL_5 + " =?";
```

You are supposed to provide an String into the `query` variable